# Mongodb insert with multiple conditions

Tags: json, mongodb, updates, mongodb-query

I'm having multiple documents in a collection, each document has this data structure :

```
{
    _id: "some object id",
    data1: [
        {
            data2_id : 13233,
            data2: [
                {
                    sub_data1: "text1",
                    sub_data2: "text2",
                    sub_data3: "text3",

                },
                {
                    sub_data1: "text4",
                    sub_data2: "text5",
                    sub_data3: "text6",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            data2_id : 53233,
            data2: [
                {
                    sub_data1: "text4",
                    sub_data2: "text5",
                    sub_data3: "text6",

                }
               ...
            ]
        },
        {
            data2_id : 56233,
            data2: [
                {
                    sub_data1: "text7",
                    sub_data2: "text8",
                    sub_data3: "text9",

                }
                 ...
            ]
        },
        {
            data2_id : 53236,
            data2: [
                {
                    sub_data1: "text10",
                    sub_data2: "text22",
                    sub_data3: "text33",

                }
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to update to a set of ids that maches some condition, update only the sub object within the document.

I've tries this:

```
db.collection.update({
    "$and": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$in": [
                    {
                        "$id": "54369aca9bc25af3ca8b4568"
                    },
                    {
                        "$id": "54369aca9bc25af3ca8b4562"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "data1.data2": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "sub_data1": "text4",
                    "sub_data2": "text5"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
   "data1.data2.$.sub_data3" : "text updated"
}
)
```

But I get the following error:

Update of data into MongoDB failed: dev.**.com:27017: cannot use the part (data2 of data1.data2.0.sub_data3) to traverse the element...

Any Ideas?

Comment: update position operator `$` can not support nested array. It means that `data1.$.data2` is acceptable but not `data1.data2.$`. I found there are more than one `data2` as element of `data1` satisfied query condition, so this position operator `$` is improper to use here because it only locates to the first place and ignore others. I think you have to fetch the whole `data1` from query before update.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) that imposes a limitation when trying to update elements of an array nested within another array.

Besides, there are some improvements you can do here:

1. For your query you don't need the $and

```
    db.collection.update(
    {
      "_id": {
        "$in": [
          {"$id": "54369aca9bc25af3ca8b4568"},
          {"$id": "54369aca9bc25af3ca8b4562"}
        ]},
      "data1.data2": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "sub_data1": "text4",
          "sub_data2": "text5"
        }
    },{..update...})
```

2. You might want to use $set:

```
    db.collection.update(query,{ $set:{"name": "Mike"} })
```

Otherwise, you might lose the rest of the data within your document.

Comment: Eventually I'v modified the data and then saved it. It was the only way to do it at this current mdb version.